# What is the fastest way to compare set of strings to one string?

Tags: c++, string, sorting, time, compare

I have set of strings and I need to find if one specific string is in it. I need to do this only one time (next time strings are different).

I'm thinking to sort strings with bucket sort and then do binary search.

Time complexity: O(n+k)+O(log n)

Is there any faster/better solution?

With set I mean more strings not std::set.

Comment: `std::find` is O(n). Unless you mean an actual `std::set`, in which case it has a `find` member function.

Comment: `std::set::find` is O(log(n))

Comment: If you're only doing it once you might as well just compare each string individually.

Comment: `std::unordered_set::find` is O(1) :p

Comment: @quantdev - After the set is constructed.  How much does it cost to construct the set?

Comment: @HotLicks, "I have set of strings" - maybe it already is? I can't be sure.

Comment: @HotLicks, ofc, I was just commenting on chris. I would just compare each string once... We miss context here.

Comment: One should of course compare length first, and one might perhaps use a scatter compare of some sort if the strings will tend to be similar or start with the same prefix.

Comment: Depending on the number of strings, the fastest way could just be a plain `O(N)` linear search. Profile different approaches and see.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To summarize the comments above in an answer. If you are loading strings to be compared on the fly and do not need them to be in a specific order, then `std::unordered_set` is by far the fastest.

`unordered_set` is a hash set and will punch your string through a hash function and find if it is already in the set in constant time O(1).

If you need to retain the order of the elements then it becomes a question what is faster of retaining a vector and doing a linear search though it, or whether it is still worth to build the hash set.

Code:

```
std::unordered_set<std::string> theSet;

// Insert a few elements.
theSet.insert("Mango");
theSet.insert("Grapes");
theSet.insert("Bananas");

if ( theSet.find("Hobgoblins") == theSet.end() ) {
    cout << "Could not find any hobgoblins in the set." << endl;
} 

if ( theSet.find("Bananas") != theSet.end() ) {
    cout << "But we did find bananas!!! YAY!" << endl;
}
```

For comparison:

If you use `std::vector` you will need O(n) time building the vector and then O(n) time finding an element.

If you use `std::unordered_set` you will still need O(n) time to build the vector, but afterwards you can find an element in constant time O(1).

Comment: How does unordered_set work when there are two strings that match search string? I need to know that there are two strings and which one are.

Comment: @user3437139 Actually, that cannot happen in an `unordered_set`. One of the constraints on the container is that it can contain at most one copy of a given value. In order to find duplicates, you can look into using unordered_multiset, which allows duplicates. Or you can look at using an unordered_map<string, int> where the int is the occurrences of each string. I recommend the latter.